# Rank and Trace of a Matrix

Tags: matrices, trace

For a real matrix $A$, $A$ satisfies $A^3=A$, $A$ not equal to $I$ or $O$.
If $\text{Rank}(A) =r$ and $\text{Trace}(A)=t$ then,

A) $r \geq t$ and $r+t$ is odd

B) $r \geq t$ and $r+t$ is even

C) $r<t$ and $r+t$ is odd

D) $r<t$ and $r+t$ is even

I know that if A^2=k.A , then Trace (A) =k . Rank (A) , but i just don't know how to apply this here .
Also tried to do A^3=A
 or ,A^3-A=O
or , A(A^2-I)=O
therefore A^2-I=O , i.e A^2=I ,therefore Trace of A^2 is n (assuming A is nxn) then ?
How to calculate rank of A and connect it to trace ?

Please help.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compute the minimal polynomial of $A$ from the equation $A^3=A$ and the fact that $A$ is neither $I$ nor $O$.  Then  what are  the two  non  zero eigenvalues?

Now  write  down $t$, $r$ and $t+r$ in terms of the multiplicity of these two eigenvalues and the answer should be clear.

Comment: Sorry i'm not so strong on discrete mathematics and in fact i'm just starting on Discrete mathematics .I have no idea how to calculate minimum polynomial for a matrix .

Comment: Well it's the polynomial with smallest degree that cancel the matrix, in that case $X^3-X$, the zeros of this polynomial gives the eingenvalues. When dealing with matrices characteristic and minimal polynomials are fundamental. Maybe have a look at a textbook of linear algebra. I find that "Algebra" by Artin is a good one.